# NP where and if statment conditions

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, if-statement, numpy-ndarray

I am currently having a problem understanding np.where in relation to if statements. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) I have heard of it being more efficient. I am trying to get a better understanding of the np.where function but I havent found any examples that are making it clear. This is the if statement I really want to convert, can anyone assist? When you convert this can you give some more conditional examples perhaps. Would numpy conditional statements work better if np.where isn't a probably solution.

For the sake of a better explaination true_list and flat_list arent really list in the real problem, they're arrays I'm appending. So I'm just going to change their name to true_arr and flat_arr.

Heres more code:

```
combo = list(element)
flat_arr = np.concatenate(combo) #changes array dimensions to what I need
sum_flat_arr=flat_arr.sum(axis=0)
salary = sum_flat_arr[2]
values = sum_flat_arr[3]

if salary <= 5000 and values > 150:
            true_arr = true_arr + flat_arr
```

true_arr is just an empty numpy array(not sure whats the best way to handle it to prefill it with the number of empty rows and columns or leave it completely blank and just append it)

flat_arr is just one whole array it looks like:

```
Out:
    [['Johnny Tsunami' 'Driver' 1000 39]
     ['Snow White' 'Pistol' 2000 40]
     ['Michael B. Jackson' 'Pistol' 2500 46]
     ['Greg Ritcher' 'Lookout' 200 25]]
```

Essentially Name Job Salary and Value, instead of dataframes I'm trying to do everything in Numpy for speed. The reason why I'm not using np.concatenate is because I hear it's slower then adding them like list. If I'm wrong please explain.

Its just appending a list. If you cant do it this way and it needs to be a function it could be np.append or np.concatenate.

End all be all if non of this applies and I have been thinking totally the wrong way I'm simply looking for a numpy way to do if statements more efficiently(faster).

Can someone shoot me in the right direction.

Comment: can you provide a sample of what is in true_list and flat_list, and where is the salary info coming from

Comment: also is 'values' a scalar?  a list?  a numpy array?  please edit your code to set example values for all those variables

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan Updated let me know if that explains it or makes it more confusing thanks for coming to my aid.

Comment: @jaypops96 Updated let me know if this explains it better

Comment: not sure that helps very much... what's this mystery "element" variable you're trying to concatenate?  also, why are you trying to use a numpy array to hold variables of different data types?  often a python list is a more efficient way of doing that. can you add a statement at the beginning something like element = <whatever>  to set a notional value for element, so we can understand what you're trying to do overall?

Comment: I think the big picture of what you're trying to do is getting lost in the little details. if you're just trying to build up a list by conditionally appending elements, there are probably easier and more efficient ways to do that with list comprehensions or for loops.  Once you start working with numpy arrays, appending becomes much more costly.

Comment: @jaypops96 yeah they are getting lost in the little details. I just want to conditionally append as quickly and effeciently as possible. I need to sum up the columns its the reason why im using np.array instead of list, tried using just a regular list and sum it up that way but its slow as well. So I'm just trying different things. I was planning on using Numpy...Numpy+Cython and see if I can increase it that way essentially I'm experimenting. I just wanted a little guidance or direction. I definitely appreciate your comments on this.

Comment: it's hard to identify why your code is slow, because you haven't provided any context.  like, is that code block within a for loop that's executing many times?  if you want better feedback, i'd post at least some psudocode for the larger picture you're trying to achieve.  As phrased currently, it's impossible to even identify the problem, let alone suggest a solution.  often when a piece of code is running too slowly, it requires a step back to fix something at a higher level, rather than tweaking individual lines.